# How to serialize multiple checkbox values by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, jquery-post

I modified the simple example of [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) as

```
  $("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var $form = $( this ),
        term = $( "input[name^=tick]:checked" ).serialize(),
        url = $form.attr( 'action' );
    $.post( url, { ticks: term, id: '55' },
      function( data ) {
          $( "#result" ).empty().append( data );
      }
    );
  });
```

This works for single checkbox with `val()` but not for multiple checkboxes in

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tick" value="'.$value.'" />
```

since `serialize() should generate`ticks: term`to be used as`term`in`$.post`.

How can I make the `serialize()` to generate appropriate data for `$.post`

**NOTE:** I do not want to serialize the entire form but only checked values of checkbox INPUT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use .serializeArray()
Ref: http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: you can store the values in array and than serialise it.

Answer (score 5):

Simple value collector :)
HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="selector" value="{value}"/>
```

JS

```
 var checked='';
            $('.selector:checked').each(function(){
                checked=checked+','+$(this).val();
            });
```

PHP

```
 $ids=explode(',',substr($_GET['param_with_checked_values'],1));
```

Answer (score 3):

In html code change `name="tick"` in `name="tick[]"` and you can use simply `$(this).serialize();` to post all checked values.

Comment: Wow, this is quite the easiest way to get multible checkbox values!

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `.serializeArray` and use it in `.post()` like this:

```
var postData = {};
var form = $('#formId').serializeArray();
for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
    if (form[i]['name'].endsWith('[]')) {
        var name = form[i]['name'];
        name = name.substring(0, name.length - 2);
        if (!(name in postData)) {
            postData[name] = [];
        }
        postData[name].push(form[i]['value']);
    } else {
        postData[form[i]['name']] = form[i]['value'];
    }
}

$.post('/endpoint', postData, function(response) {

}, 'json');
```

`postData` will contain all form elements except the disabled ones. All checkbox values will be passed as an array just like when doing a normal form submission.

Answer (score 1):

```
let $form = $(".js-my-form");
let $disabled = $form.find(':input:disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
let formData = {};
$.each($form.serializeArray(), function (index, fieldData) {
    if (fieldData.name.endsWith('[]')) {
        let name = fieldData.name.substring(0, fieldData.name.length - 2);
        if (!(name in formData)) {
            formData[name] = [];
        }
        formData[name].push(fieldData.value);
    } else {
        formData[fieldData.name] = fieldData.value;
    }
});
$disabled.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
console.log(formData);
```

Its a variation of Stanimir Stoyanov answer with possibility  to serialize disabled fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
term = $("#input[name^=tick]:checked").map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
term.join();
```